# Prove that a given function is an isometry

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $U$ is an $n \times n $ orthogonal matrix and $\bar{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the mapping
$i: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $i(\bar{x}) = U\bar{x} + \bar{b}$ is an isometry. I assume that we use the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by, $d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\bar{x},\bar{y}) = \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2  \right)^{1/2}$

Comment: show that $\|Ux\|_2 = \|x\|_2$ for every $x$

Comment: Does *isometry* mean that it preserves the norm? Mapping $i$ does not: $\| i(0)\|=\|b\|$ which is not $0$ in general.

Comment: @JankoBracic Isometrie means $d(i(x),i(y))=d(x,y)$.

Comment: From  the comment of Surb I see that you want that the distances are preserved. Hence $\| i(x)-i(y)\|=\| Ux-Uy\|$ which is possible as $U$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$ for every $x$ using orthogonality (use $UU^T=I$ and $\|x\|=x^Tx$). Then observe that $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_2$ where $\|\cdot \|_2$ is the standard euclidean norm.